# How to determine when someone loses internet connection with Safari 11?

Tags: javascript, safari, offline

So I am trying to fire a modal when a user on the site loses connection to the internet/wifi.

This solution works for Chrome and Firefox - but doesn't work with Safari 11.0

```
 window.addEventListener('offline', lostConnection);

  function lostConnection() {
    modals.lostConnection.open();
  }
```

When researching I've tried using navigator.onLine and also the library "Offline.js" <-- these don't work either for Safari 11.0

Answer (score 0):

MDN about [navigator.onLine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.onLine):

> In Chrome and Safari, if the browser is not able to connect to a local area network (LAN) or a router, it is offline; all other conditions return true. So while you can assume that the browser is offline when it returns a false value, you cannot assume that a true value necessarily means that the browser can access the internet.

This property is not trustable, so, in my opinion, the best workaround is an ajax call to a server-side page. If the browser is offline, then the connection will fail and you can handle either case accordingly.